# Why isn't this Elasticsearch query using combined queries returning the expected result?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm querying my index by documents that must have "Thomas" appearing in some manner in the `lastName` field and should also return return results according to a `geo_point` query. The `geo_point` query appears in the `should` clause because there is a possibility multiple will be passed in. If any match, I want the document to return as a hit. Any idea why this isn't working? I've followed the documentation [as outlined here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html).

"should: At least one of these queries must match. Equivalent of OR"

```
{
"sort": [{
    "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
    }
}],
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "query_string": {
                "default_field": "lastName",
                "query": "Thomas"
            }
        }],
        "should": [{
            "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "5mi",
                "coordinates": "32.798913, -79.998085"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that your `coordinates` field is of type `geo_point`?

Comment: Yes, the mapping is correct.

Comment: Are you sure that the `coordinates` are specified with first the latitude and then the longitude and not the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Nesting is important. In the above code, `should` is living alongside `must`; therefore, it functions similar to "Find last names like Thomas OR anyone living 5mi within Charleston". The below nests the `geo_point` query as a sibling with any other `must` clauses.

"Find last names like Thomas AND (5mi within Charleston OR 5mi within Atlanta OR etc.."

```
  {
  "sort": [{
      "_score": {
          "order": "desc"
      }
  }],
  "query": {
      "bool": {
          "must": [{
                  "query_string": {
                      "default_field": "lastName",
                      "query": "Thomas"
                  }
              },
              {
                  "bool": {
                      "should": [{
                          "geo_distance": {
                              "distance": "5mi",
                              "coordinates": "32.798913, -79.998085"
                          }
                      }]
                  }
              }
          ]
      }
  }
}
```